# mutate new dataframe id duplicate with old dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frame, this is just a sample , database have approx 1 million of records.

```r
data1<-data.frame(
  'External ID' = c(86364,"ARV_2612","AGH_2212","IND_2622","CHG_2622"),
  sector = c(3,3,1,2,5),
  col1=c(1,1,0,0,0),
  'Enternal code'=c(1,1,1,1,3),
  col3=c(1,1,0,0,0),
  col4=c(1,0,0,0,0),
  col5=c(1,0,1,1,1)
)

data2<-data.frame(
  'External ID' = c(53265,"ARV_7362",76354,"IND_2622","CHG_9762"),
  sector = c(3,3,1,2,5),
  col1=c(1,1,0,0,0),
  'Enternal code'=c(1,1,1,1,3),
  col3=c(1,1,0,0,0),
  col4=c(1,0,0,0,0),
  col5=c(1,0,1,1,1)
)
```

new to R,now i am looking for a function to mutate my one data frame (data2) like. the code while will automatically find the column "External ID", then add a new column in  data2 like duplicate and this column will show  Y or N if the external_id in data2 present in data1(external ID)

so basically  if External_ID in data2 present in External_ID of Data1 then Y else N add  new column in data2 having Y,N

I have tried this but this giving on all records

```
data1$duplicate <- "Y"
data2 <- left_join(data2, data1) %>% mutate(duplicate = replace_na(duplicate, "N"))
```

I mean that I want some code to find some column in one frame that might be the same type of data in the other frame, and make some inferences ... and then run %in% to determine the Y/N determination

the output should be like

[image]

Comment: By "duplicate": do you mean that only `External ID` is found in both data frames, or that every value in the row is the same, as in your example?

Comment: data2$duplicate <- data2$External.ID %in% data1$External.ID

Comment: yes External ID is found in both data frames

Comment: @Cleland but the column selection should also be dynamic because we have many same column like "External.ID"

Comment: rjunkie2, it's not clear what you mean. There is only one new column in your desired output, and it in that example is based on `External.ID`. Do you mean that you want some code to find some column in one frame that might be the same type of data in the other frame, and make some inferences ... and then run `%in%` to determine the Y/N determination? Why aren't you performing similar lookups in all of the other columns in `data2`?

Comment: yes the same thing i want @r2evans, i just edited the same in question

Comment: Well, since all other columns are named the same, then one might infer that you want them all to be checked against either (I'm assuming names must be identical). In this case, are you expecting five *more* columns in `data2`? (They would all be `"Y"` in this case due to the identical sample data, not sure if that's a concern.)

Comment: no, all column cant be identical name the column i am referring  it can be "External ID", and can be onother name like Ext_id in onother dataframe

Comment: maybe this is what you need (you need dplyr library): 
data1$duplicate <- 1
data2 <- left_join(data2, data1) %>%
  mutate(duplicate = replace_na(duplicate, 0))

Comment: I am trying to create a function to the same thing

Comment: So effectively you want to compare *every* column in one frame with *every* column in another frame (since you cannot use names) and check for set-membership with `%in%`. (For that, you'll need to explain what you think the output should be.) I think I'm really off base, but this all suggests you might benefit from explaining why you need this, perhaps a little bit of context.

Comment: so basically  if External_ID in data2 present in External_ID of Data1 then Y else N add  new column in data2 having Y,N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all , for your help.

I have tried below and it helped me

```
getexidnames<- function(data1,data2){
  (d1name <- names(data1) %>% stringr::str_subset("^External|ID"))
  (d2name <- names(data2) %>% stringr::str_subset("^External|ID"))
  list(d1name=d1name,
       d2name=d2name)
}
getexidnames(data1,data2)


data2 <- data2 %>% 
  mutate(duplicate = if_else(External_ID %in% data1[,map_lgl(data1,~length(intersect(.,data2$External_ID))!=0 & class(.)==class(data2$External_ID))], "Y", "N"))
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the comments, not sure if this solves your question:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data2 %>% 
    mutate(duplicate = if_else(External.ID %in% data1[,map_lgl(data1,~length(intersect(.,data2$External.ID))!=0 & class(.)==class(data2$External.ID))], "Y", "N"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the base R option like below

```
within(
  data2,
  duplicate <- c("N", "Y")[External.ID %in% data1$External.ID + 1]
)
```

which gives

```
  External.ID sector col1 Enternal.code col3 col4 col5 duplicate
1       53265      3    1             1    1    1    1         N
2    ARV_7362      3    1             1    1    0    0         N
3       76354      1    0             1    0    0    1         N
4    IND_2622      2    0             1    0    0    1         Y
5    CHG_9762      5    0             3    0    0    1         N
```